# Bot with Private Endpoint failing with initialized = failed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service, azure-private-link

I have an azure bot, and I am adding a private endpoint. I am working through this document:
[Private Endpoint & Direct Line App Service Extension Configuration with Bot Services and App Service](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/private-endpoint-amp-direct-line-app-service-extension/ba-p/3736194)

I completed the 'Enable bot Direct Line App Service extension' section, but when I make the call to confirm the direct line extension and bot are configured I get a value of false from initialized.

The call to https://<your_app_service>.azurewebsites.net/.bot returns:    {"V":"1.2.0.0.e84fbf1863c30abdf7b40dc11a91bc86044d49a2","K":true,"IB":true,"OB":true,"Initialized":false}

According to [the document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/private-endpoint-amp-direct-line-app-service-extension/ba-p/3736194#:%7E:text=If%20the%C2%A0initialized%C2%A0value%20of%20the%C2%A0.bot%20endpoint%C2%A0is%20false%2C), a value of false means the Direct Line App Service extension is unable to validate the App Service extension key.
I have triple checked that the key is valid, and I have tried using the alternate key.

How can I find more information about why it can't validate the key?

How can I troubleshoot this?